# Google API to track document view and edits - google sheets

Tags: api, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I maintain ~450 unique Google Sheets for all of the teachers in our school district (updated nightly using a python script). For auditing and reporting purposes I would like to track opens and edits of these Sheets.

I've found the Changes [resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes) that should be able to help me identify edits, but that's only getting me halfway there. Is there any Drive API Resource out there that will identify page views (count, most recent) by user?

Comment: you can use the watch API as well

Answer (score 0):

### Track Google Drive document changes using the Reports API from the Admin SDK.

What you are trying to do can be achieved using the Reports API.You can have a list of all the file IDs and use the [activities.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/activities/list) method and set the userKey parameter to "all" so that you get the activities from any user, or set a specific email address or user ID to get the information from a specific user only.

The applicationName parameter needs to be set to "drive" so that it recognizes that it is the Google Drives report the one you are accessing, and then for the filters parameter you can use for example "doc_id==12345" (replace 12345 with the file ID) to get the activity report from a specific document.

An example:

[image]

Note: Be aware that this can only pull information from the [last 6 months.](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7061566)